# Align text correctly in pygame

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

I am working on a text-field implementation in pygame. The issue is that the location at which text is rendered is not consistent although text is always rendered to the same (x,y) position. For example, rendering an underscore characters yields this (character is rendered at top):

[image]

When I add more characters, the underscore moves to align with the remaining characters:

[image: _]

This does not happen if you type these characters in the search bar of stackoverflow.com for example.

Is there a way to make the rendering consistent all the time so that all characters get rendered to their final position regardless of surrounding context?

Answer (score 0):

When you [`render`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render) a text from a [`pygame.font.Font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font) object, then the result is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html). When you use [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) then the *dest* argument specifies the top left of the *source* Surface.

If you want to align the bottom of the text then you have to compute the top, dependent on the height ([`get_height()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_height)) of the rendered text Surface:

```py
desired_height = ... # height of a capital letter like "A"

text_surface = m_font.Render()
text_y = y + max(0, desired_height - text_surface.get_height()

scree.blit(text_surface, (x, text_y )
```

Comment: Thanks, this kind of works but it does not solve the problem completely. You still see that the text moves a bit up and down as you type. I think that I should leverage other types of info related to text.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a property of the font called the ascender: the number of units from the font's baseline to the top of the bounding box. We shift the text to the to sit on top of it's baseline:

```
text_y + font_ascender - text_height
```